# How do I post JSON data to CodeIgniter Controller?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a simple jQuery post function that is posting JSON data to a CodeIgniter controller. The post succeeds from the client but I do not receive a response from the server. I'm pretty new to CI so I'm sure I'm doing this wrong.

```
function post(){
        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/create", {username:"testUser",password:"userpassword"},function(data) {
                var test = data;
        });
    }
```

So I am passing two strings to the user controller's create action. To test I am just trying to get the 'username' from the posted data and send it back to the calling function. Currently the response is empty.

```
 public function create(){
        if($this->input->post('newuser')){
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            echo json_encode(array('username'=>$username));
}
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: where is this `post()` located? in an external script? or in the page?

Comment: Just for fun: enable php_short_tags in php.ini so that you can turn all calls to `<?php echo "foo"; ?>` to `<?= 'foo';?>` ... also, use `site_url()`, as in `<?= site_url('user/create');?>`. Lastly, there are many threads around StackOverflow that can guide you how to remove index.php from your URLs ;) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the post contains the key `newuser` but yet, you're only send 2 strings with the key 'username' and 'password'. You'll need to modify the JavaScript part to something like this:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/create", {newuser: 1, username:"testUser",password:"userpassword"}...
```

Or, just remove the `if` statement from the `create()` function.

Comment: HA! I missed the removal of that line.. how did I miss that. Thanks man. doh

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function post(){
  var url ="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/create";
   $.post(url, {username:"testUser",password:"userpassword"},function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var test = data;
   });
 }
</script>
```

## Controller

In your controller you check new user in post method and you didn't send post new user so if condition is false and response is null
You should check

> $this->input->post('username')

```
public function create(){
  if($this->input->post('username')){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    echo json_encode(array('username'=>$username));
  }
}
```